# Authentication error when fetching real time Twitter data

Tags: r

I am trying to fetch real time Twitter data using Twitter's official APIs. For that, I generated all the API keys and secret tokens using Twitter developer page. But at the time of authentication I got an authentication error. I've already loaded all the required packages but that did not solve my problem.

My code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(httr)
api_key <-"API key"
api_secret <-"API Secret"
access_token <-"Access Token"
access_token_secret <-"Access Token Secret"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,
                    access_token_secret)
```

I updated and loaded all necessary packages, seemed like it would be a pretty straight-forward process to authenticate. Instead, I get this error:

> Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:This most
>   likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()

I read a lot of the other SO questions on this topic, nothing solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Twitter application settings in apps.twitter.com. They must be read/write in order to make Streaming API requests.

Another thing to check is your system time. If it is more than 5 minutes off your Streaming API requests will fail.